# How do I convert an array into an object within array - Angular and Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, javascript-objects

What I am trying to do is take an array within an object within an array within an object (I know my data structure is ridiculous, any help with that would be great also) and convert the last array into an object with a "key":"value". I'm using Angular 1.5.7 if there is anything in Angular that could help do this. I know that probably makes no sense. I couldn't figure out a way to say what I am trying to do clearly so let me show you:

I start with an object like this:

```
{"instructor":[{"instructor_emails":[ "test@test.com","tester@tester.com"]}]}
```

And I want it to be:

```
{"instructor":[{"instructor_emails":{ "email":"test@test.com","email":"tester@tester.com"}}]}
```

I tried a couple of things and the closest I found was:

```
instructor.instructor_emails.map(function(e) {
        return { email: e };
});
```

But it doesn't quite do what I'm trying to do... Any thoughts?

Comment: There cannot be two keys with the same name in an object.

Comment: yup your right...I actually already had it right with the above mention code I tried, it returns an array of objects containing the ```"email" : "example@example.com"``` I'm just trying to manipulate it wrong..thanks for pointing that out. I should have realized it from the get go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was correct all along (Thanks Alex)

```
instructor.instructor_emails.map(function(e) {
    return { email: e };
});
```

Returns:

```
{instructor:[instructor_emails[{"email":"example1@example1.com",{"email":"example1@example1.com"}]]}
```

The data structure is still ridiculous but it will suffice for what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) for optimal data storage, particularly concerning [classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). To transition between traditional `OOP` languages, like Java, to JavaScript you can use [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Below is a snippet i created using TypeScript:

```js
/// <reference path="definitions/jquery.d.ts" />
console.clear();
var Instructor = (function () {
    function Instructor(name, emails) {
        if (name === void 0) { name = ""; }
        if (emails === void 0) { emails = []; }
        this.name = name;
        this.emails = emails;
    }
    Instructor.prototype.addEmail = function (email) {
        if (email === void 0) { email = ""; }
        //Run validation
        if (email.length > 3) {
            this.emails.push(email);
        }
    };
    Instructor.prototype.getEmails = function (type) {
        if (type === void 0) { type = "array"; }
        var self = this;
        type = type.toLowerCase();
        var getEmails = {
            string: function () {
                return self.emails.join(" ");
            },
            object: function () {
                return self.emails.map(function (e) {
                    return { email: e };
                });
            }
        };
        if (getEmails[type] === void 0) {
            return this.emails;
        }
        else {
            return getEmails[type]();
        }
    };
    return Instructor;
}());
var instructors = [
    new Instructor("Michael Bennet I", ["test@test.com", "tester@tester.com"]),
    new Instructor("Michael Bennet II", ["test@test.com", "tester@tester.com"]),
];
console.log('array', instructors[0].getEmails());
console.log('object', instructors[0].getEmails("object"));
console.log('string', instructors[0].getEmails("String"));
```

```css
/*
// This is TypeScript

class Instructor {
 constructor(public name: string = "", public emails: string[] = []) {

 }
 public addEmail(email: string = "") {
  //Run validation
  if (email.length > 3) {
   this.emails.push(email);
  }
 }
 public getEmails(type: string = "array") {
  var self = this;
  type = type.toLowerCase();
  var getEmails = {
   string: function () {
    return self.emails.join(" ");
   },
   object: function () {
    return self.emails.map(function (e) {
     return { email: e };
    });
   }
  }
  if (getEmails[type] === void 0) {
   return this.emails;
  } else {
   return getEmails[type]();
  }
 }
}

var instructors: Instructor[] = [
 new Instructor("Michael Bennet I", ["test@test.com", "tester@tester.com"]),
 new Instructor("Michael Bennet II", ["test@test.com", "tester@tester.com"]),
];
console.log('array',instructors[0].getEmails());
console.log('object',instructors[0].getEmails("object"));
console.log('string',instructors[0].getEmails("String"));
```

```html
<p>Object can have their own functions to "get" data they contain in unique ways.</p>
<p>This way, you can get the same data in several different ways</p>
```